# Command Messages - classification design question

Tags: java, domain-driven-design, cqrs, event-sourcing

I'm trying to design one service using event sourcing. One use case is - when command arrives, I have to execute some logic and transform object from one MODE to other one. Now, the "problem" I'm facing is to decide between these two options for command messages:

Option 1: (put mode directly into name of the command message)

```
SetToManualModeCommand{
  int val = 22;
}
SetToAutoModeCommand{
  int val = 22;
}
SetToSemiAutoModeCommand{
  int val = 22;
}
SetTo...ModeCommand{
  int val = 22;
}
```

Option 2: (put mode as an enum inside single command message)

```
enum Mode{
  AUTO, 
  SEMI_AUTO, 
  MANUAL;
}

SetToModeCommand{
  Mode mode;
  int val = 22;
}
```

- modes are not changing that often - but they can change. If they change - in option 1 I have to make new class. In option 2 I have to add one additional enum value.

Do you see any drawbacks/benefits of any of these 2 options, or are they more less the same?

Comment: "when command arrives, I have to execute some logic and transform object from one MODE to other one" - Which object to be transformed? You have a Mode object which you want to transform to another mode? or you want to use a Mode object corresponding to the command object? and everywhere val=22 ?

Comment: This is just an example. val represents additional data in message that is used during transformation. It will not be hardcoded but received from other services (but it is generally the same between all commands). Object that needs to be transformed is another one (some aggregate root (eg. SomeAR{})).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the context you’ve given I don’t see a convincing argument either way.  I know you’re talking about commands, not events, but try thinking about it from the event subscribers point of view.  Is the significant event that the mode changed in some way, or that it changed to a specific value?  In other words, would subscribers want a single ModeChanged event with details inside the event, or would some subscribers want just ModeChangedToManual and others just want ModeChangedToAuto, etc.  You may consider the event storage system you’re using and how easy it is to create a filtered subscription.

It’s convenient (not required) that each command creates a single event.  If subscribers would prefer a single event and you have 4 commands issuing that event it makes the system just a tiny bit more complicated, and those tiny bits tend to add up.  If it’s better for subscribers that you have 4 separate events, then have 4 separate commands.

Comment: Consumers of this are only interested in modechanged event - so they don't actually care that much about which mode. Mode is more for internal logic that will in the end produce events based on the mode. Then I guess it would be better to have single command with enum inside...

Answer (score 0):

As a general principle - make the implicit explicit. Therefore make a command for each 'mode'. But I honestly don't think there is much in it.

Clearly what you actually do is very dependant on the context of the system you are building. How often do new modes get introduced?

I would say, however, that you should definitely have an event for each mode.

Comment: Modes are introduced maybe once in 2-3 years lets say. I guess enum option would suit better here then.

Answer (score 0):

See what you code wants. If command sending code is a switch statement that encodes your mode, and event consuming code is also a switch statement that decodes your mode, then just send a mode as a command/event payload.

If consuming code for each mode is in different places - then make it easy for each place to subscribe to right mode - make different events for each mode.

Answer (score 0):

My general approach is to not include classification as structure.  Having classification as data seems to be easier.

Another example that is similar to yours would be different types of customers: `GoldCustomer`, `SilverCustomer`, or `BronzeCustomer`.  A while later (2-3 years) the business may decide to add a `PlatinumCustomer`.

An enumeration *may* be better but for anything that is not *fixed* I would not use structure (neither class nor enumeration).  Field positions in some sport may be an enumeration since these are fixed.  If they change then it is significant enough to warrant code changes.

To that end I would have some domain concept represent the mode in a more generic/fluid fashion but YMMV.